# Angular, how to initially show the first set of data in an array and allow a click even to change the array index

Tags: arrays, angularjs

New to angular. Found a couple similar examples, but having some issues.

Essentially trying to create a thumbnail image list with the selected full size image shown. Mostly like what amazon has.

Have a data structure like this:

```
this.imgList = [
    {imgTitle: 'title', imgDescription: 'description', imgUrl: '1.jpg', imgTnUrl: '1tn.jpg'},
    {imgTitle: 'title', imgDescription: 'description', imgUrl: '2.jpg', imgTnUrl: '2tn.jpg'}
```

The examples I've seen use ng-repeat, but those seem to load all the full size images before a click event happens. Found a couple libraries that don't use ng-repeat, but can't get those to work.

Would have thought I could do something like {{x.imgList[0].imgTitle}}, but not sure how to change it after someone clicks a thumbnail.

Is there an easy way to do something similar without pre-loading all the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular you can create a  [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)  that has a injected $scope.

```
$scope.imgList = [
{imgTitle: 'title', imgDescription: 'description', imgUrl: '1.jpg', imgTnUrl: '1tn.jpg'},
{imgTitle: 'title', imgDescription: 'description', imgUrl: '2.jpg', imgTnUrl: '2tn.jpg'}

$scope.showFullSize = false;
```

Then in your template you can use the scope variable similar to how you had above except with the use of the [ng-src directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) and ng-if to render or not render the image.

```
<img ng-if="showFullSize" ng-src="{{imgList[iterator].imgUrl}}"/>
<img ng-if="!showFullSize" ng-src="{{imgList[iterator].imgTnUrl}}"/>
```

Additionally, you can define your logic to set the showFullSize property which will show/not show the full size image. If you want the request to be made to pull the image you can use the angular show/hide directives in place of the if.

Comment: That mostly makes sense. How would I change the iterator? Would that just be another scope variable that I change on click?

Comment: Exactly, you can just put a ng-click on the thumbnail image that uses another function on the scope to change the showFull size.  $scope.showBigImage = function(){ $scope.showFullSize = true;}